# How to delete a file from a directory using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(100) 
set @cmd= 'xp_cmdshell ''del "C:\root\sfd_devtracker\' + @deletefile + '"''';
EXEC (@cmd)
```

I had tried the above code, but fails with error Must declare scalare variable @deletefile.

Anyone one can figureout whats wrong here??

Comment: Really not sure why you tagged this `[oracle]`. There's more than enough SQL Server experts here.

Comment: i added to make sure it gets a wider audiance, anyways i will be happy if someone helps me out here @APC

Comment: Please don't try to attract a 'wider audience'. All that happens is that people (like me) who know Oracle and don't know T-SQL wonder why you brought us here.

Comment: Why would you want to run that *through the database*? Why not create a SQL Server Agent job? Calling `xp_cmdshell` requires relaxing security restrictions

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the variable @deletefile just like you declared @cmd above

DECLARE @deletefile varchar(20). You can use varchar(100) if your file name is too long.

Set the filename that you want to delete in @deletefile variable and then run your query.

SET @deletefile='YourFileName'. Overall it should be like below

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @deletefile VARCHAR(20)
set @deletefile='YourFileName' 
set @cmd= 'xp_cmdshell ''del "C:\root\sfd_devtracker\' + @deletefile + '"''';
EXEC (@cmd)
```

Comment: @abhishekyadav Then please mark the response as an answer - which you haven't been doing since you started. That is how SO works - people ask questions and get them answered so that others with similar questions can find answers.

Answer (score 0):

As the error messages says, you have not declared the variable `@deletefile`, or set it anywhere.

You need to do

```
DECLARE @deletefile NVARCHAR(255) = 'FileNameHere'
```

or similar

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have declared and set the variable "@deletefile" to specify file name you wish to delete?